# Why does fsolve seem not iterate towards the solution?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to sovle a two non-linear equation system using fsolve and dogleg method. My objective function along with its jacobian is like this

```
function [F jacF]= objective(x)

    F(:,1) = ((((x(:,2)./10).*k).*(x(:,1)./100)).^2).*(rZ - Rs) +(( Cmax .* ( x(:,1)./100 ) ).^2).*( w.^2.*(rZ - Rs) ) - (((x(:,2)./10).*k).*(x(:,1)./100)); 

    F(:,2) = (x(:,2).*k).^2.*(iZ - w.*Ls) + (x(:,2).*k).^2.*x(:,1).*((w.*Ls)./200) + x(:,1).*((w.*Ls)/200).*(w.*Cmax).^2 + (w.*Cmax).^2 .*(iZ -(w.*Ls));

    if nargout > 1 % need Jacobian
        jacF = [- k - (k.^2.*x(:,2).*x(:,1).*(Rs - rZ))./50,                         - (k.^2.*x(:,2).^2.*(Rs - rZ))./100 - (Cmax.^2.*w.^2.*(Rs - rZ))./100;
                2.*k.^2.*x(:,2).*(iZ - Ls.*w) + (k.^2.*Ls.*x(:,2).*w.*x(:,1))./100,(Ls.*Cmax.^2.*w.^3)./200 + (Ls.*k.^2.*x(:,2).^2.*w)./200];
    end
end
```

Then my configuration for fsolve looks like this

```
    options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter-detailed','PlotFcn',@optimplotfirstorderopt);
%     options.StepTolerance = 1e-13;
    options.OptimalityTolerance = 1e-12;
    options.FunctionTolerance = 6e-11;
    options.MaxIterations = 100000;
    options.MaxFunctionEvaluations = 400;%*400;
    options.Algorithm = 'trust-region-dogleg';%'trust-region'%'levenberg-marquardt';%
%     options.FiniteDifferenceType= 'central';
    options.SpecifyObjectiveGradient = true;
    fun= @objective;

    x0 = [x1',x2'];

    % Solve the function fun
    [gwc,fval,exitflag,output,jacobianEval] =fsolve(fun,x0,options);
```

Being the values of the equations

```
Rs =
    0.1640
Ls =
   1.1000e-07
Cmax =
   7.0000e-11
w =
   1.7040e+08
rZ =
   12.6518
iZ = 
   14.5273
K =
    0.1007
x0 = 
    70.56 0.0759
```

My problem comes because I don't understand why fsolve seems not to iteratate over `x(:,1)` as i was expecting. I do know that the solution for the above system and parameters should be `x1=58.8` and `x2=0.0775`. 
In order to test the convergence of the method I am setting as initial guess `x0 = [x1*(1+20/100) 0.0759] = [70.56 0.0759]` ( 20 percent error in x1 and a higer value  on x2), but the solution given by fsolve is the initial point, why is this? Am I doing something incorrect in my settings?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: added the equations, with generic coefficients
[image]

Comment: Could you provide us the actual equations you are trying to solve, not only the code? It would be easier to check for code errors. Also, what is the expected range of the variables? You could try to normalize them. I will add an answer to your question with a figure, trying to show you the problem with your function.

Comment: The range of the variables is `0<=x(:,1)<=100` and `0<=x(:,2)<=13`. I will edit the post with this and the equations

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, I tried to figure out the problem, but there seems to be none, except the "ill conditioned" behaviour.

I tried to observe the behaviour of your function, and notice:

```
x = -50:50;
y = -50:50;

[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
F1 = zeros(size(X));
F2 = zeros(size(X));
for i=1:size(X,1)
    for j=1:size(X,2)
        f = objective([X(i,j) Y(i,j)]);
        F1(i,j) = f(1);
        F2(i,j) = f(2);
    end
end

figure; 
subplot(1,2,1)
surf(X,Y,F1); shading interp; xlabel('x1');ylabel('x2');zlabel('F_1'); colorbar
subplot(1,2,2)
surf(X,Y,F2); shading interp; xlabel('x1');ylabel('x2');zlabel('F_2'); colorbar
```

[image]

`F1` is the first element of your vector function and `F2` is the second element.
Notice that `F1` is almost constant in the entire range (it changes very little from 0 to 1). Notice, also, that for a big part of the surface of `F2`, you have bright yellow part, which means this function also does not change a lot. For any given initial condition, the norm of the `F` function is small enough, so any point in this region will be considered "good enough for zero of the function".
We also notice that some values in your equation have very different orders of magnitude,

```
Rs =
    0.1640
Ls =
   1.1000e-07
Cmax =
   7.0000e-11
w =
   1.7040e+08
rZ =
   12.6518
```

which makes it more difficult to solve. The best solution is to try to make a change of variables to normalize the input and output. That should scale the independent variables and the vector valued function, to improve the numerical inaccuracy of your model.

---

Ok, you have now provided your equations and your problem seems to be worse (in a numerical sense) than I originally thought.

Your equations are:
[image]

Given that `x1` is a function of the second variable, you actually have only 1 independent variable, not 2, as it previously seemed. Therefore, you may write `F1 = f1(x2)` and `F2=f2(x2)` as both functions are functions only of one variable. You have two alternatives to solte this system of equations of 2 equations and 1 variable (notice the problem here?)

1. The first option - the easy one - is to solve each equation separetely. By doing that, you will get two different values for `x2`, one that satisfies the first equation and another satisfying the second equation. That is not helpful.
2. The second option - the hard one - is to solve both equations simultaneously. The hard part here is that you must define a precise criterion to be satisfied when solving the equation. See, you have two equations, but one variable, so how do you know the solution you found is the 'optimal' one? A commonly used criterion is to solve both equations in a [least-squares sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares), ie, you find the value of `x2`that minimizes the sum of the squares `S=F1^2+F2^2`. 
   Now, your equation with generic coefficients does not exactly matches the code you provided, so I don't know which of these `ai`, `bi` coefficients are the `Rs`, `Ls`, `Cmax` etc, but you can generally solve your equation in a least-squares sense as:

   a1 = rand;
   a2 = rand;
   a3 = rand;
   b1 = rand;
   b2 = rand;
   b3 = rand;
   b4 = rand;
   b5 = rand;

   fun = @(x2) myfun(x2,a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5);
   x0 = 1;
   [X,FVAL,EXITFLAG] = fminsearch(fun,x0)

   function S = myfun(x2,a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5)
       x1 = a2*x2./(a1*x2.^2+a3);

   ```
   f1 = a1*(x1.*x2).^2 - a2*x1.*x2 + a3.*x1.^2;
   f2 = b1*(x1.*x2).^2 + b2*x1.*(x1.*x2).^2 + b3*x1.^3 + b4*x1.^2 + b5*x1;

   S = f1^2+f2^2;
   ```

   end

Notice that you will have to properly define the constants and the initial estimate. Since `x1` is a functon of `x2`, you calculate it inside the body of the function. Then, you calculate each component of the function and then creates the sum of the squares. The function [fminsearch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) finds the minimum of the sum of the squares - the solution of your equation.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I was wondering, when you say `change of variables to normalize` do you mean that I have scale either F1 and F2 in such a way that the equations have the same order of maginitude? Or that I have to scale only the variables in such a way that F1 and F2 have the same order of magnitude? Could you provide an example for me ?

Comment: You should try do both. With the actual equations, it will be easir to explain. But essentialy, use normalized variables, say `t1` and `t2`, in such a way that `0<=t1,t2<=1' and properly the vector function, so that  0<='F1,F2<=1'.

For the independent variables, you can do `x1=t1/100` and `x2=t2/100`.
For the F function, that is not the best solution a proper nondimensionalization of the equations ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization),[2](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~angenent/519.2014s/problems/non-dimensionalization.html))should work better.

Comment: I think I start to understand Thales, I have added the equations so that you could ease the explanation.

Comment: Thanks again Thales for the detailed explanation. When you mean `properly define the constants` you mena by following [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization ?

Comment: No. I actually mean to write `a1`, `a2` etc as a function of your parameters `Rs`, `Ls`, `Cmax` etc. Notice that in your code, the first term of `F1` is:

`((((x(:,2)./10).*k).*(x(:,1)./100)).^2).*(rZ - Rs)`

but the first term of your equation with generic coefficients is:

`(x1*x2)^2*a1`.

How does `a1` relates to `k`, `rZ`, `Rs` etc?

Comment: Hi Thales, actually I did what you suggested, I am putting `a1` as function of `Rs,Ls,Cmax...` in the form i.e. `a1= (k./1000).^2.*(rZ-Rs)`. So in my expression for `F1` and `F2`I just take the parameters as constants that multiply the unkowns `x1` and `x2`